# Swift - how to return 'contained in' objects in same order as array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an array that contains a list of objectId's in a very specific order. I'm then running a PFQuery, with a "containedIn" constraint. How do I order the results of this query so that the returned objects are in the same order as their corresponding objectId's in the array?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFQueries can only be ordered by the values in certain columns. So you could use the "orderByDesecending" or "orderByAscending" with a key (such as date, or alphabetized by name), but there is no "orderToMatchTheOrderOfMyArray."

I would recommend just sorting them manually. It shouldn't be hard. I'm not a swift dev, but here is the pseudo code:

```
sortedObjects = [] //start with empty array
for each ObjectId in MyListOfObjectIds { //loop through your ordered objectIds
    for each object in MyQueriedObjects { //loop through the objects you got from the query
        if (ObjectId == object.objectId) { //if you've found the correct object
            sortedObjects.addObject(object); //add it to the list
            break; //move on to the next ordered objectId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're a hero. I was literally at my wit's end, this is so clever. I thank you profoundly